# How to make a dynamic survey avoiding excessive usage of if statements?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a questionnaire where each answer leads to a different question (similar to what a decision tree or a state machine does).

It is fairy simple to accomplish this using if-else statements, but I expect to have more branches and depth to my "tree".

I'm afraid at some point I won't be able to read the code anymore.

Is there a cleaner, easy-to-read way to write this?

Here's an example of what I could figure out so far:

```
q1 = raw_input("Q1 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n")
if q1 == "1":
   q2 = raw_input("Q1.1 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n")
   if q2 == "1":
      q3 = raw_input("Q1.1.1 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n\n")
   if q2 == "2":
      q3 = raw_input("Q1.1.2 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n\n")
if q1 == "2":
   q2 = raw_input("Q1.2 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n\n")
   if q2 == "1":
      q3 = raw_input("Q1.2.1 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n")
   if q2 == "2":
      q3 = raw_input("Q1.2.2 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n")
   if q2 == "3":
      q3 = raw_input("Q1.2.3 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n\n")
if q1 == "3":
   q2 = raw_input("Q1.3 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n\n4)\n\n")
   if q2 == "1":
      q3 = raw_input("Q1.3.1 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n")
   if q2 == "2":
      q3 = raw_input("Q1.3.2 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n")
   if q2 == "3":
      q3 = raw_input("Q1.3.3 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n")
   if q2 == "4":
      q3 = raw_input("Q1.3.4 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n")
```

Comment: Can you attach an example of what it does at the moment? It would be useful to see what it looks like.

Comment: Yes.  I suggest that you learn about directed graphs and state machines.  Then you'll be able to represent this as a graph in some form convenient to you; the main loop will consist of a "present position" variable and generic logic to get you to the next position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary for your questions to treat it separately from your code flow, therefore avoiding excessive usage of if statements to make it more readable.

Here's how your example should look like with this solution:

```
questions = {"0": "Q1 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n",
             "1": "Q1.1 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n",
             "2": "Q1.2 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n\n",
             "3": "Q1.3 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n\n4)\n\n",
             "11": "Q1.1.1 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n\n",
             "12": "Q1.1.2 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n\n",
             "21": "Q1.2.1 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n",
             "22": "Q1.2.2 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n",
             "23": "Q1.2.3 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n3)\n\n",
             "31": "Q1.3.1 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n",
             "32": "Q1.3.2 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n",
             "33": "Q1.3.3 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n",
             "34": "Q1.3.4 \n\n1)\n\n2)\n\n"}

q1 = raw_input(questions["0"])
q2 = raw_input(questions[r1])
q3 = raw_input(questions[r1+r2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nested `dictionary`:

```
surveyDict = {
    "1" : {
        "1" : {
            "more_data" : {...}
        }
    },
    "2" : {
    }
}
```

Then you can basicly keep track of last dictionary to attend like in this **pseudo-code**:

```
currentDict = surveyDict
while currentDict:
    answer = input("Whatever")
    if answer in currentDict:
        currentDict = currentDict[answer]
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to specify the structure of the questionnaire in some way, and that's probably going to be somewhat verbose simply because it has to include all the question text and all the answer choices. But what you can do is separate the different parts of the application logic - in particular, separate the question and answer definitions from the processing of input and printing of output, and that might make your code look a bit cleaner.

One way that might be decent is to create a class to represent a question and its answers. An instance of the class would allow you to retrieve the next question depending on what answer is given. Something like this:

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, answers):
        # question is a string, answers is a list of N strings
    def set_next(self, answer_choice, next_question):
        # answer_choice is an index from 0 to N-1 and
        # next_question is the Question object that should be used
        # next if that answer is chosen
    def ask(self):
        # this prints self.question and the answers using raw_input()
        # and returns the Question object (if any) that was set with
        # set_next() which corresponds to what the user typed
```

Then you can turn your questions into instances of this object:

```
Q1 = Question('What is up?', ['Down', 'Left', 'Right'])
Q11 = Question('something about down?', ['A', 'B'])
Q1.set_next(0, Q11)
# etc.
```

and you can keep asking questions using a simple loop:

```
question = Q1
while question is not None:
    question = question.ask()
```

There are various ways to make this more elegant, but this will get you started. Note that what you'd be doing here is making a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of your question objects. If you do a web search, you can read up more on DAGs and other methods of representing and processing them that you might prefer to use.